# Always overwrite if exists?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table looks like:

```
_id, subID, textInput, attribute1, attribute2
```

When I create a new record, it saves 5 rows... all with the same subID. If I create another record with the same subID, it saves 5 rows, giving me a total of 10 rows for that subID.

What I would like is if subID already exists to just overwrite the rows that are already there. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use INSERT OR REPLACE, but you'll have to put a unique index on subID.

Alternatively, you can query the table for the subID and if found, use a simple UPDATE instead.  If not found, use an standard INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `INSERT OR REPLACE` command. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html for details.